# Defining fmap for data type

Tags: haskell, functor

So I've got those data types :

```
data Stuff a = Stuff (StuffPart a) (StuffPart a) deriving (Show,Eq)
data StuffPart a = Add a (StuffPart a)| End deriving (Show,Eq)
```

, now is it possible to write a fmap function for Stuff ? Something like :

```
instance Functor Stuff
  where 
   fmap f (Stuff x y) = Stuff (f x) (f y)
```

Obviously my fmap won't work but what can I do to make it work.
I have also tried code like :

```
instance Functor Stuff
  where 
   fmap f (Stuff x y) = Stuff (f x) (fmap f y)
```

Somehow I feel lost in terms of fmap functions..

Comment: you need one for `StuffPart`, same as a list...  Or just enable `DeriveFunctor` to do the job for you...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`fmap` has the signature:

```
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

So that means that it will - given a function that maps from `a` to `b`, produce a function that maps `Stuff a` to `Stuff b`. But **the attributes of `Stuff` are not `a`s**, so you **cannot call `f` on the arguments directly**.

So that probably means you want to **make `StuffPart a` a `Functor`** first. For instance:

```
instance Functor StuffPart where
    fmap f (Add x y) = Add (f x) (fmap f y)
    fmap _ End = End
```

It looks like `StuffPart` is your custom defintion of a list (`[]`).

and then we can simply define:

```
instance Functor Stuff where
    fmap f (Stuff x y) = Stuff (fmap f x) (fmap f y)
```

Note that the `fmap`s we call here (the ones in boldface) refer to the function we defined above (in the context of `Functor StuffPart`).

**EDIT**: you do not *have* to make `StuffPart` a `Functor` per se. If you do not really want that, you can simply define a function `foo :: (a -> b) -> StuffPart a -> StuffPart b` and call that function, but this actually looks like bad code design to me, since if you later alter the definition of `StuffPart` then parts about `Stuff` have to change as well, making it harder. But if you really want that, you can use:

```
instance Functor Stuff where
    fmap f (Stuff x y) = Stuff (foo x) (foo y)
        where foo (Add x y) = Add (f x) (foo y)
              foo End = End
```

Comment: Thank you !! Oh well I understand, but isn't there any other option to do this without making Stuffpart a Functor ?

Comment: @itonva: yeah you can define a function `foo :: (a -> b) -> StuffPart a -> StuffPart b` and then call that function. But here it seems reasonable to make `StuffPart` a function as well.

Comment: Ok i got it. Thanks for your help, I really appreciate this :)

Comment: @Wilem Van Onsem:yes actually it is better to make `StuffPart` a `Functor`, I just wanted to know if there were any other possibilities.

Comment: @itonva If you don't want to dive into those things (though personally I think it's a good to implement such `Functor` instances manually) you can add `{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}` pragma which allows you to add `Functor` inside `deriving` clause.

Answer (score 5):

You also need a `Functor` instance for `StuffPart`:

```
instance Functor Stuff where
  fmap f (Stuff p1 p2) = Stuff (fmap f p1) (fmap f p2)

instance Functor StuffPart where
  fmap f (Add x sp) = Add (f x) (fmap f sp)
  fmap f End = End
```